# CoordinatorLayout Collapse or Expand AppBar on scroll end

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Is there a way to move the AppBar up or down, based of percentage of view collapsable view visible when the scroll ends. In the [CheeseSquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) app, the Toolbar can get stuck in between when scroll ends.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the exact use case of [SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP):

> Upon a scroll ending, if the view is only partially visible then it will be snapped and scrolled to it's closest edge. For example, if the view only has it's bottom 25% displayed, it will be scrolled off screen completely. Conversely, if it's bottom 75% is visible then it will be scrolled fully into view.

Which was added in [version 23.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html) of the Android Support Library.

You can also use it via XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
```

Comment: SNAP Wow :) Thanks